# Python convert tuple to strings(numbers) aligned in columns excel/csv

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have lists with numbers. for example:

list1=(0123, 0234, 0235)
list2=(3333300000, 4444400000, 5555500000, 6666600000)

I used:

```
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest
with open("file.txt", 'w') as outcsv:
    writer = csv.writer(outcsv)
    writer.writerow(["column1", "column2"])
    for row in zip_longest(list1, list2):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

But the output is truncated numbers like zeros are gone and end digits became zeros (since my sample is just an example but I'm working with 10 columns and different numbers). i want them to look like this:

[image: In excel file]

I tried converting each item in the list into string first or adding `'` in front like in excel but not all items are converting (some are still truncated) and some are having multiple ''''' before each item. I use:

```
for x in list1:
    y="'"+x
    list1.remove(x)
    list1.append(y)
```

Please help.

Comment: Please give a working example.  `list1 = (0123,0234,0235)` declares three octal numbers in Python 2.7 and doesn't work in Python 3+ due to a syntax change for octal numbers.  Also `"'" + 123` doesn't work.  You can't add strings to integers.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Also mention Python version.  It makes a difference as you can see.  The `csv` module also works differently between 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: You will likely have to use a different library to write a true excel file so you can specify the format of the cells.  Excel reads `"0123"`, `0123`, and `123` as the number `123` from a `.csv` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing into Excel, import the column as `text` to save the 0's.

After you have the csv file. Open a new workbook in Excel click `Data` then `From Text` go on with your regular import process but on Step 3 choose `text`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it is excel removing leading 0s  not csv file. if you open your file with text editor you can see the number

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can write your numbers as `="0123",="0234",="0235"`.

This way Excel will preserve the leading zeros

Comment: Thank you i think this helps